# Worksheets are blank in published dashboard after server extract refresh

Tags: tableau-desktop

Tableau 2021.4.2

In desktop tableau, I can refresh all extracts and everything looks as expected.

I publish to the server and everything looks as expected.

Then after the scheduled server refresh of the extracts, the sheets that use two of my three data sources go blank.

What is causing this?